# Convert CDATA node to encoded string in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

**TL;DR** - in .Net and XmlDocument/XDocument is there an easy way (XPath?) to find `CDATA` nodes, so they can be removed and the contents encoded?

**Details**...

My system has lots of situations where it builds XML strings manually (e.g. string concatination, rather than building via XmlDocument or XDocument) which could contain multiple `<![CDATA[...]]>` nodes (which could appear at **any** level of the structure)... e.g.

```
<data><one><![CDATA[ab&cd]]></one><two><inner><![CDATA[xy<z]]></inner></two></data>
```

When storing this data in a SQLServer XML column, the `<![CDATA[..]]>` is automatically removed and the inner text encoded... this is standard for SQLServer which doesn't "do" `CDATA`.

My issue is that I have complex code that takes two instances of a class, and audit-trails differences between them... one or more could be a string property containing XML.

This results in a mismatch (and therefore an audit-trail entry) when nothing is actually changing, because the code creates one format of XML and SQLServer returns a different form, e.g...

```
// Manually generated XML string...
<data><one><![CDATA[ab&cd]]></one><two><inner><![CDATA[xy<z]]></inner></two></data>
// SQLServer returned string...
<data><one>ab&amp;cd</one><two><inner>xy&lt;z</inner></two></data>
```

Is there an easy way in .Net to process the manually generated XML and convert each `CDATA` node into it's encoded version, so I can compare the string to the one returned by SQLServer?

Is there a `SelectNodes` XPath that would find all those elements?

(And before anybody states it, the obvious solution is to not use `CDATA` in the manual creation of the XML in the first place... however, this is not possible due to the sheer number of instances.)

Comment: _this is not possible due to the sheer number of instances_: This statement seems to be a fallacy. It's most likely possible, just not desirable.

Comment: Couldn't you process the XML strings before converting to `XmlDocument`/`XDocument` with `Regex.Replace` method version?

Comment: @NetMage - Regex definitely has it's place, and I do use it regularly... but trying to parse XML with it is a dangerous game. See the [notorious answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/930393) to somebody asking if they can parse XHTML with regex

Comment: @freefaller Ah, but you are not parsing, you are trying to convert a single element. I supposed there are potential issues with comments and strings if they happened to contain a CDATA pattern, but that seems pretty unlikely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy with one `foreach` loop and `ReplaceChild`:

```
using System.Xml;

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<data><one><![CDATA[ab&cd]]></one><two><inner><![CDATA[xy<z]]></inner></two><three><inner>a &lt; b</inner></three></data>");

foreach (var cdata in doc.SelectNodes("//text()").OfType<XmlCDataSection>())
{
   cdata.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(doc.CreateTextNode(cdata.Data), cdata);
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

Outputs

```
<data><one>ab&amp;cd</one><two><inner>xy&lt;z</inner></two><three><inner>a &lt; b</inner></three></data>
```

Another option would be to run the XML through an XSLT identity transformation with XslCompiledTransform and e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you @Martin. Didn't occur to me to test the type of the nodes... I was concentrating on trying to find an appropriate xpath. The first part of your answer is perfect